# asp.net mvc Ajax.BeginForm duplicating elements

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ajax.beginform

I am using ajax to load data using partial view and at the same i have implemented search functionality. Its working fine but when i keep my search textbox empty and then hit search button then my layout gets duplicated.
here is my code

**controller** :

```
     public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string search)
     {
        if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return View(await _employeeRepository.GetAllEmployeesAsync());

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            return View(await _employeeRepository.GetAllEmployeesAsync());
        return PartialView("_EmployeeList",(await _employeeRepository
            .GetAllEmployeesAsync())
            .Where(x =>x.EmployeeName.StartsWith(search,
                    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
     }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
    @model IEnumerable<MvcDemo.Models.Employee>


   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Employee", new AjaxOptions
   {
       OnFailure = "record not loaded",
       HttpMethod = "GET",
       UpdateTargetId = "employeeData",
       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
   }))
   {
      <input type="text" name="search"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="search by name..."/>

      <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    }
    <div id="employeeData">
        @Html.Partial("_EmployeeList", Model);
        @* i have used render partial as well*@
    </div>

   @section Scripts {
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryajax")
   }
```

**BundleConfig**:

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryajax").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"));
```

**Layout.cshtml** :

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryajax")
```

Can anybody tell me where i am going wrong ?
 Keeping the input blank and clicking on search button duplicating the layout.
Take a look at my screenshot 
[screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li6S4.png) 
 [screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzOCS.png)
 [screen 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzkPA.png) 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Wondering if you could add a js that will capture the submit event and check the value of 'search'. If there is no value, then don't bubble up (don't process the click event)..

Comment: But i have handled in my controller inside my if condition if value is null for search. Are you talking about validating the search input ? That's secondary thing but my question is why duplicating if i am returning same view if my search is null.

Comment: can you add partial view "_EmployeeList" code

Answer (score 1):

If search text is null or empty, you are returning the index view, instead of this return partial view.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    return PartialView("_EmployeeList", (await _employeeRepository.GetAllEmployeesAsync()));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,it works but i would much appreciate if you can explain me exact reason behind duplication. Is it  my ajax script was loading twice or something ? Please explain.

Comment: one more thing i would like to know how do i redirect to create page asynchronously ? I have create button on my above using(ajax.beginform()) index.cshtml is it write place to place that create link and navigate to create page asynchronous way ?? pls suggest

Comment: On search button click, you are calling the index action method, in this method you are checking whether search text is empty or not, if empty then you are returning in index page. Here what happens your index page will return to ajax request and binds into the `<div id="employeeData">..</div>`.